# How to divide a text file into two parts?

Tags: java

I am reading a text file to parse data using `Scanner`. The pattern is not unique, and it repeats making it difficult to parse. I want to split the text file into a second part in the same location of the original file. The second file should start from a particular string. With this I can point to different files while using Scanner.

```
filePath = Paths.get(fileLocation);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(filePath);
```

The text file content looks like this

```
Initial data  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx Inputs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx Outputs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to put the data starting from Outputs into a second text file

Comment: There's not enough context to help.  Please update the question with a sample input which demonstrates the problem, along with the code that's not working, and a sample of the expected output.

Comment: @AndrewS  I do not have the code to split the file. I am still working on it with BufferedReader.

Comment: _The pattern is not unique_? Is there a multiple **Initial data**, and/or **Inputs, Outputs**?

Comment: @zlakad The data is repeated in inputs and outputs like the name, number and address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        //br is the bufferedreader
    String line=null;
        boolean outputflag=false;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        if(line.contains("Outputs")) {

        outputflag=true;
//if you do not want the word Outputs in the output file just add 7 to start index
line=line.substring(line.indexOf("Outputs"),line.length());
//write line to outputs file
        }

        if(outputflag) {
        //write line to ouputfile
        }
        }
```